# Sword damage with armor in Minecraft Bedrock

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How can I calculate how much damage I deal to an opponent? The Minecraft wiki shows damage taken when the opponent is hit with no armor.
But if my opponent has full iron, and I hit them with a diamond sword, is it possible to calculate how much damage they just took?

Answer (score 2):

The fun way to know it would be to go into creative mode, spawn a few *volunteers*, give them some armor, and science it out :)

The quick way to know it is to check the [Wiki page on armor](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Armor#Defense_points), and the [part specific to Bedrock Edition](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Armor#Bedrock_Edition).

According to those pages, each *armor point* reduces 4% of the damage taken. For a full, unenchanted set, that would be 80% less with diamond or netherite, 60% less with iron, 48% with chainmail, 44% with gold <sub>(huh, I thought it was *better* than iron but less durable!)</sub>, and 28% less damage with leather.

If your diamond sword deals 8 damage points per hit, somebody wearing iron armor would take only 3.2 damage points, without any enchantments or critical hits.

Comment: Nope. Golden armor is worse than iron. Quite a surprise to some of you. Don’t know why, but I’ll take it as I LOVE iron.

Comment: Iron is what I wear until i have mending on my netherite

Comment: I completely skip diamond